# Build image with php and use it in production with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am starting with Docker and i think i miss something quite obvious. I have a really simple multi stage Dockerfile who looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine as test_php
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD ["php-fpm"]

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine as test_nginx
COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=test_php /app/public public/
```

And a docker-compose who looks like this:

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: test_php
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      target: test_nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./public:/app/public
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

This works in development (i have in public folder just a simple index.php with phpinfo() ).
My default.conf for nginx have this:

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

to make the link with the php service.

The problem is for production. I build my image based on the Dockerfile and then i push it to Docker Hub.
To use my image on production, i wanted to do something like this in a new docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    image:mynickname/myimage
```

So i now use my image created on the dockerfile but i don't have anymore the php service so the nginx conf doesn't work anymore.
I was thinking to keep my original docker-compose (with php service) but in this case, i don't use my image...
I clearly miss something so my question is:

What is the "best" way to go from dev to prod with a basic configuration like this ? (php and nginx).
How can i use my image in production and having php working fine? 
Are there other ways?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your first step (still in the development environment) should be to delete the `volumes:` that overwrite the code in the image.  Injecting a per-deployment nginx configuration is reasonable; overwriting what you `COPY` in with host content means that you're not actually testing what you're going to deploy.

A given Compose service can have both a [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) and an [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image).  In this case Compose will tag the image it builds with the name you give it, instead of choosing its own name, and then you can [`docker-compose push`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/) the built images to a registry.

Finally, when you go to run this setup somewhere else, you can remove the `build:` blocks and Compose will pull the `image:`s it needs.  The resulting `docker-compose.yml` will roughly look like:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   target: test_php
    image: mynickname/php
  nginx:
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   target: test_nginx
    image: mynickname/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

You can also set this up with [multiple `docker-compose.yml` files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) where the "standard" `docker-compose.yml` file has the production version (including the `image:`), and this gets extended with a `docker-compose.override.yml` that adds the `build:` declarations.  In a production setup you'd only copy the base file to the target system.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer, your time and your explanations. I changed my code and now it works :)
But since i can have only one repo in Docker Hub for free, i cheated a bit and did mynickname/project:nginx and mynickname/project:php
I am still wondering if it's possible to use only one image as output? 
I was thinking to use only the nginx image (which is much lighter than php and integrates php because we did a copy in the dockerfile) but it's not working (i'm still missing the php service in nginx.conf)
Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot again